# BlackBerry Ripple emulator Start Services does nothing

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks, ripple, blackberry-widgets

I want to package and launch my BlackBerry Hello World application for WebWorks. For developement, I am using the Ripple emulator. The Ripple simulator says:

> The build and deploy services are not currently running, would you like to start them?

After pressing the button `Start Services` nothing happens and no errors are in the error console.

Comment: I got the build services working by uninstalling Ripple version 0.9.15 and installing version 0.9.16. See my answer to this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17316347/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem was caused by not running the application from a web server. (I pointed the url directly to the file system.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons this might be happening. The first is that Chrome is preventing this from happening.

1. Open the Tools --> Extensions screen in Chrome
2. Enable 'Developer Mode' checkbox if it isn't already
3. Are you running Chrome in Incognito mode?  If so enable the 'Allow in Incognito' checkbox

The other options is that nodejs is being blocked. If you're on windows, I'd suggest making sure that all user permissisons are enabled to allow you to run Chrome in a way that it can launch external processes.