# Blackberry Ripple Emulator on click start services does nothing

Tags: blackberry-10

I want to package and launch my BlackBerry Hello World application for WebWorks. For developement, I am using the Ripple emulator. The Ripple simulator says:

```
The build and deploy services are not currently running, would you like to start them?
```

After pressing the button Start Services nothing happens and no errors are in the error console.and i also did below steps as i have searched and get this result:

There are two reasons this might be happening. The first is that Chrome is preventing this from happening.

```
Open the Tools --> Extensions screen in Chrome
Enable 'Developer Mode' checkbox if it isn't already
Are you running Chrome in Incognito mode? If so enable the 'Allow in Incognito' checkbox
```

The other options is that nodejs is being blocked. If you're on windows, I'd suggest making sure that all user permissisons are enabled to allow you to run Chrome in a way that it can launch external processes.

And After doing all when ever i refresh page it says

The build and deploy services are currently running at localhost:9910. and after loading that page this message not visible but

The build and deploy services are not currently running, would you like to start them? message still there! please explain what's wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: My Local host was running on port 80 but now i have changed my local host running port 80 to 9910 then the refresh error msg "The build and deploy services are currently running at localhost:9910." is not visible any more but still i getting same msg for build i.e. The build and deploy services are not currently running, would you like to start them?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved by removing Ripple extension version 0.9.15 and installing version 0.9.16 (latest as of this posting), and restarting Chrome. When you click the 'Start Services' button, the console should appear displaying a build service start up message.

Comment: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v1_0/ripple_emulator_extension_release_notes.html

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/html5/download/

Install the latest beta and it should work!